# Is it typical for adjuncts to have a higher salary than postdocs?

Tags: postdocs, salary, lecturer

I've been noticing that sometimes adjunct lecturer salaries are higher than those of postdocs, in math. I was wondering if that is typical and why that is the case.

Comment: That's what it costs to get people?  Adjuncts expect payment since they are off the tenure track whereas postdocs can still be exploited by the vanishingly small chance of grabbing the brass ring?  [In any case, it's about supply and demand not "fairness".]

Comment: Adjuncts are usually paid per course.  They do not have a salary at all.

Comment: It's usual for experienced, full-time, teaching-only faculty to be paid more than postdocs.  Even forgetting real-world factors, wouldn't you think this should be the case unless you thought research was a much more valuable activity than teaching?